# Apex Test for a simple ApexClass

Tags: unit-test

Hi i have a simple Apex Class , the only used as a controller for a visulforce page , and contain mainly soql jobs,

But i just cant pass 72% covarge , no matter what Test in writing,

the code below , can please some one help me with the Test class

Thank you.

```
    public class PrivareaApex
{
 private ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl {get; set;}

 public List<account> conts {get; set;}
  public string  currentRecordId {get;set;}
  public integer  Pax {get;set;}
public List<Invoice1__c> Invo {get; set;}

 public PrivareaApex(ApexPages.StandardController std)
 {

  stdCtrl=std;
  setupContacts();
 }

 private void setupContacts()
 {

 String Roomname=[select Unit_Name__c from account where Id=:stdCtrl.getId()].Unit_Name__c;
  conts=[select id, Name, PersonEmail, Phone, Union_Member_contact__pc from account where Unit_Name__c=:Roomname];
  Pax=[select COUNT() from account where Unit_Name__c=:Roomname];
  Invo = [select Name, Invoice_Date__c, Billed_Amount_NIS__c, Payment_Method__c,Billing_Frequency__c from Invoice1__c where Account__c=:stdCtrl.getId()];


 }

          }
```

Comment: Hi @OronM, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help Center](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help) and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you.

Comment: Please post your test class which covers 72% of the controller class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You class is pretty simple from a "cover Lines" point of view. All you need to do is instantiate the controller properly.

From a proper test method point of view, you will have to do a bit of data population before you instantiate your controller and add some asserts to ensure it is working as you would expect.

This will get you 100% coverage but do not confuse it for a proper test class until you fill int he missing pieces.

```
@isTest
private class exampleBasic{


    private static testmethod void coverage(){
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'TestAccount', Unit_Name__c = '1234');
        insert a; //Create an account object to work with

        //create the rest of your data
        /* ....Data Created HEre *///

        //Create an instance of the standard controller for the Account record created above
        ApexPAges.standardController std = New ApexPages.standardController(a); 

        //Instantiate your controller - with the standardcontroller
        PrivareaApex con = New PrivareaApex(std)        

        //Do your assertions
        /* .....Assertions */
        //The below may not be the correct assertions based on your use case so update as necessary
       system.assertNotEquals(null,con.currentRecordId);
       system.assertNotEquals(null,con.Pax);
       system.assertNotEquals(null,con.invo);
       system.assertNotEquals(null,con.conts);
       system.assertNotEquals(null.stdCtrl)

    }

}
```